# invalid composite literal type validator.FieldError

Tags: golang

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Не понимаю, почему нельзя так сделать... Подскажите, пожалуйста

```
    validationErrors = validator.ValidationErrors{
    &validator.FieldError{
        FieldError: errors.FieldError{
            Field: "Name",
            Tag:   "required",
            Err:   fmt.Errorf("Name is required"),
        },
    },
    &validator.FieldError{
        FieldError: errors.FieldError{
            Field: "Age",
            Tag:   "gte",
            Param: "18",
            Err:   fmt.Errorf("Age must be greater than or equal to 18"),
        },
    },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Я так понимаю, речь идёт о пакете `github.com/go-playground/validator`?

В этом пакете тип `FieldError` определяет интерфейс. У него нет данных, есть только набор операций, которые реализации должны предоставлять.

Вам нужно найти тип, который реализует все методы `FieldError`, и использовать объекты этого типа для заполнения массива `ValidationErrors`

В пакете такой тип есть, но вы им воспользоваться не сможете. Это внутренний тип [`fieldError`](https://github.com/go-playground/validator/blob/master/errors.go#L167)

Сделайте свой тип по образу и подобию `fieldError`, включая все методы, и пользуйтесь им.